# Position an element splitted up with css

Tags: css

I have a heading/small text positioned at the right side of a div container.

HTML:

```
<div id="img"></div>
<h2>Heading<small>A long long text</small></h2>
```

CSS:

```
#img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
```

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/U8BnX/

I'm trying to achieve the following, while I **can't modify the given html code**. I want to get this out of the given html code with plain css:

[image: Result]

I tried it the following way, but this fails when the div container is wider, because the padding is set to a static value. (http://jsfiddle.net/4p7qh/) Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could we modify the HTML with JS?

Comment: No, just basic css. Background is that the shown result is for mobile phones and so I can only apply css rules through media queries.

Comment: I'm curious, why can't you modify the html code so it could represent the actual structure of the document?

Comment: Indeed I can modify the html code. But I must ensure that I can "switch" between the presentation now and the desired result with pure css that gets applied with media queries. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pure CSS solution:

This is how I'd probably modify the HTML structure to allow for more flexibility.  I added a container element and took the small element out of the heading element:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="img"></div>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <small>A long long text</small>
</div>
```

Updated stylesheet:

```
/* Common styles */
#img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}

/* Layout 1 */
.container h2 { display:inline; font-size:24px; }
.container small { font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; }


@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    /* Layout 2 */
    .container {
        position:relative;        
    }

    .container h2 { position:absolute; top:-20px; left:0; }
    .container { padding-top:40px; }
}
```

Live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/U8BnX/2/

Try narrowing the preview pane, layout 2 kicks in when the width is 400px or below.
Although maybe not a perfect solution, this still works properly if you change the size of the #img element.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve the problem as I imagined: When the div gets wider (e.g. 80px), the headline h2 stays not at the same place. I want this to work with a div non static in width.

Comment: Not possible unless you modify the HTML or use javascript to modify the DOM and/or recalculate positions/widths.

Comment: What HTML structure would you take to switch between the two outputs with css only?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the other output you need to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
#img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
}
h2{
    left:-50px;
    position:relative;
}
small{
    display:block;
text-indent:60px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve the problem as I imagined: When the div gets wider (e.g. 80px), the headline h2 stays not at the same place. I want this to work with a div non static in width.